# Echo Javascript Variable in Php to another page

Tags: php, javascript

I have code which passes php variable to another page on my site:

```
echo'<a class="btn btn-danger" style="margin-left:10px;width:120px;float:left;"  href="fullsizemarket.php?imageid=',$imageid,'&action=removed">Remove from Cart</a>';
```

I am able to retrieve the php variable $imageid by the following:

```
$imageid = htmlentities($_GET['imageid']);
```

I want to also pass in this code the value of a javascript variable. The variable is set in an earlier part of the code as follows:

```
     var rowcount
```

I don't know how to pass var rowcount in the same echo code as I pass $imageid. What is the code to do this?

Comment: If the variable is defined in Javascript, then it is already too late, because your PHP code runs _before_ the page arrives at the user, and before the Javascript runs. Of course, if you absolutely have to do this, you could _send_ the data to a PHP page once the page has loaded, using AJAX.

Comment: To clarify, it would work like this:
User requests page -> PHP runs -> user gets page with AJAX code in it -> AJAX runs and requests page in the background -> PHP runs and receives variable.

Comment: @LonelyWebCrawler I don't know ajax. Would this be hard to implement?

Comment: ...or without Ajax you can add a click handler that changes the href attribute to include the current value of `rowcount`.

Comment: @user1605871 No, AJAX is really simple if you use jQuery (which you should). Once you have jQuery set up, you can use the `$.get()` function to request a page and send it the contents of that variable. However, you should think hard about whether this is really necessary, or if you can restructure your code so that PHP does not the variable from Javascript. Here's a link to the function: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: @nnnnn How would I do this? I'm not familiar with click handlers.

Comment: @user1605871 Once again, this is really simple with jQuery, but also works without. Without jQuery, you'd say something like `document.getElementById("someid").addEventListener("click", changeAttribute, false)`, where `changeAttribute` is a function. See the excellent MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How bout following:

```
echo 
"<a class='btn btn-danger' 
    style='margin-left:10px;width:120px;float:left;' 
    href='fullsizemarket.php?imageid=$imageid&action=removed&rowcount='
    onclick = \" this.setAttribute('href', this.getAttribute('href')+rowcount) \"
 >Remove from Cart</a>";
```